# SimpleModal Loading Image Does Not Deactivate

Tags: jquery, loading, simplemodal

When I open a SimpleModal window, the Loading image will not quit running until the window is closed. The windows simply open two images and some text.
Here is the code:
 (sorry, stackoverflow will not allow me to post the code)

Hide is simply display:none, and BAPhotos is currently not defined.

Comment: Since the intent of a modal window is to usually block the user until they've interacted with the modal content, the default cursor style is the wait icon. As you mentioned below, the solution is to update the CSS cursor property to the desired value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having the same problem, most likely all you need to do is find #simplemodal-overlay in your css file and change cursor:wait to cursor:default or whatever cursor attribute you want to use, but is you use default, the cursor will remain the same inside or outside of the box unless you have defined it differently.

(Jeeze! I had to use another browser and another e-mail address just to post this unless I wait 8 hours! Lighten up stakoverflow! You're a little overboard in security there!)

Comment: The 8-hour thing is to stop people from posting an answer that says "Never mind!  I got it!" two minutes after they post the question, which is highly annoying for everyone else.